# Implementation of the conjugate gradient repetition method on an equation of the Volterra type

Tags: definite-integrals, gradient-descent

Please help me solve this equation.
Use the conjugate gradient method to solve the problem below:

$$
Au=∫_0^tk(t,τ,u(τ))dτ
$$
$$
t∈[a,b]
$$
$$
f∈c[a,b]
$$

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: First, I want to know that the problem is correct, since wherever we look for the Volterra integral equations, the Volterra integral form is as follows:$$Au=∫_0^tk(t,τ)u(τ)dτ$$

Comment: Second, in the conjugate gradient method, we must use the following rule:$$Au=f$$
$$u_(k+1)  = u_k  + α_k s_k
$$

Comment: $$r_(k+1)  = f- 〖Au〗_(k+1)$$
$$s_(k+1)  = r_(k+1)  + β_k s_k$$
$$∝_k=‖r_k ‖^2/〖(〖As〗_k,s_k)〗^, $$
$$β_k=‖r_(k+1) ‖^2/‖r_k ‖^2 
$$

Comment: For more information, see Theoretical Numerical Analysis: A Functional
See Analytical Framework by Kendall E. Atkinson, ed. 2009, p. 4.6

Comment: But I do not know where to begin